# problem with writing to mifareclassic tag

Tags: android, exception, mifare

I am trying to read and write to a MifareClassic tag. so far I have been able to set up my application to receive intents in foreground. to read a tag I first get a MifareClassic instance, authenticate to it and read a block. it works fine.

but when I write to the tag nothing happens. the code seems to be executed without any problem but the data on the tag does not change. the funny part is that **I tried to write to the tag without authenticating first**. the code executed again without throwing any exceptions. but when I tried to **read** a block without authenticating first I got an Exception (transceive failed).

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);


        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

        IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
        filters =  new IntentFilter[] {ndef, };
        techListsArray = new String[][] { new String[] { MifareClassic.class.getName()} };

        if(nfcAdapter!=null && nfcAdapter.isEnabled() ){}
        else{

            Toast.makeText(this, "nfc not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //finish();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, filters, techListsArray);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

    }


protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);



    MifareClassic mfc = MifareClassic.get(tagFromIntent);
    mfc.connect();
    byte [] data2=new byte[16];
    for(int i =0;i<16;i++)
        data2[i]=0;

   //auth = mfc.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(4, key[1]);

    int blo=mfc.sectorToBlock(4);
    mfc.writeBlock(blo,data2);
    mfc.close();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

the access bits on the card for the data block in question is set to 100. so according to the MifareClassic documentation to be able to write to this block I should have used key B.(but I am able to read a block with key A)

apparently if you use the wrong key to authenticate to the card and then call writeblock(block,data) you **won't get an exception**. in the mean time if you use the wrong key to authenticate and then call readblock(block) you will get an exception.

apparently you can do no authentication at all and call writeblock function. and still you won't get an exception. but the data won't be written to the card.